# valgrind LEAK SUMMARY: definitely lost

Tags: valgrind

I write a class 'Data' as following.

```
//code in .h file
class Data{
private:
    int col = 0;
    int row = 0;
    float **data = NULL;
public:
    //Constructor
    Data();
    Data(int r, int c);
    Data(int r, int c, float **data1);
    Data* getX();
};

//code in .cpp file
Data::~Data(){
    for(int i = 0; i < this->row; i++){
        delete[] this->data[i];
        this->data[i] = nullptr;
    }
    this->row = 0;
    this->col = 0;
}

Data::Data(){
    this->col = 0;
    this->row = 0; 
    this->data = nullptr; 
}


Data::Data(int r, int c,float **data1){
    this->row = r;
    this->col = c;
    this->data = new float*[r];
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++){
        this->data[i] = new float[c];
        memcpy(this->data[i],data1[i],sizeof(float)*c);
    }
}
Data* Data::getX(){
    if(this->col <= 0) throw missing_data();
    int r = this->row;
    int c = this->col - 1;
    Data *data = new Data(r,c,this->data);
    return data;
}
```

It can compile and run normally. Then when I scan the code with valgrind, it prompts that the code has a memory leak.

```
==1247551== 400 bytes in 5 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 181 of 182
==1247551==    at 0x483E217: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:640)
==1247551==    by 0x11C074: Data::Data(int, int, float**) 
==1247551==    by 0x11C707: Data::getX()
```

Where is the memory leak problem in this code?
Thank you!
Here is my code in main().

```
    Data *X = this->data->getX();
    GHInfoAF<float> GandH = Divide::APdividebinning(set,ghinfo,X,sbtp->getMaxBining(),tempqpoint);
    G_H.push_back(GandH); 
    delete X;
    X = nullptr;
```

Where is the memory leak problem in this code?

Comment: Are you doing `delete` for the `Data*` returned from `getX()`? Please show how this `Data` class is used in your code

Comment: There are only 2 new expressions in your 3 arg ctor, it must be one of them. Build with debuginfo (-g) and you'll see which one.

Comment: Thanks for your attention.  I have deleted `Data*`. Here is my code in main(). 

```
Data *X = this->data->getX();
GHInfoAF<float> GandH = Divide::APdividebinning(set,ghinfo,X,sbtp->getMaxBining(),tempqpoint);
G_H.push_back(GandH); 
delete X;
X = nullptr;
```

Comment: @Judy, you missed the deletion of `this->data` in destructor

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!!@kuro @Paul Floyd  I have found the cause of the leak. In the destructor, I forgot to release the pointer `this->data`. So, when i add `delete[] this->data; this->data = nullptr;`, it has been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the destructor, I forgot to release the pointer this->data.
So, when I add

```
delete[] this->data; 
this->data = nullptr;
```

it has been fixed.

Comment: Good. You probably don't need to reset the pointer to `nullptr`. Only do that if the pointer is being reused. In a destructor everything is just "going away" and (generally) never going to be reused.